# To add an class object in nsmuttable array of another class

Tags: xcode

I have two classes *results* and *flight* segment

```
Result
{
    // Here some properties declared and
    // Nsmuttable array also to store flight segment class object 
}
```

I create object of both classes and adding in this way

```
[objresult.flightsegmentarray addobject: objflightsegment]
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure you have properly declared the 'flightsegmentarray' property on the 'objresult' object and have initialised it before trying to add objects.

To declare the property - assuming your objresult is of type ObjResult - you should write on your ObjResult .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *flightsegmentarray;
```

Then, you must initialise this, typically in your .m file:

```
- (id)init {
   if ((self=[super init])) {
      _flightsegmentarray = [NSMutableArray new];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Now, once your objresult object has been initialised, you will have an empty mutable array available and you can begin adding objects:

```
objresult = [[ObjResult alloc] init];
objflightsegment = [[ObjFlightSegment alloc] init];
[objresult.flightsegmentarray addobject: objflightsegment];
```